# Dynamically naming tuples for redis

Tags: python, redis

I have a csv file in which each line contains a person's ID # and then a bunch of attributes. I want to be able to create a tuple for each person that contains all their attributes and then name the tuple some variation of their ID  #.

All these tuples will then be added to a set in redis for storage.

I can't seem to figure out how to create a tuple that is named after the persons ID#.

I know its not best practice to dynamically name variables, but I would rather not put all the tuples in a list or set to then put into a redis set (which is a must); it just seems inefficient and cumbersome.

This is the code I have now:

```
with open('personlist.csv','rb') as f:
for line in f:
        row = line.split(',')
        personID = row[0]
        attrb1 = row[1]
        attrb2 = row[2]
        attrb3 = row[3]
        # Need to name tuple here and define as (attrb1, attrb2, attrb3)
        r.lpush('allpersonslist',tuple)
```

Comment: Can you expand on your question? Are you just trying to create a set in redis that contains all people?

Comment: Why not use the `csv` module? It will keep you from hitting all sorts of syntax issues in your CSV file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example needs additional code to function. I'm assuming you are using a redis API such as redis-py. The variable `r` is an open connection to redis.

```
import pickle

with open('personlist.csv', 'rb') as f:
    for line in f:
        row = line.split(',')
        personID = row[0]
        attrb1 = row[1]
        attrb2 = row[2]
        attrb3 = row[3]
        #put the attributes in a tuple
        tuple = (attrb1, attrb2, attrb3)
        #serialize the tuple before adding it to the set
        r.set("person/%d" %personID,pickle.dumps(tuple,-1))

def getPerson(Id):
    return pickle.loads(r.get("person/%d" %Id))
```

You can call `getPerson(5)` to return the tuple associated with a person of ID 5.

Comment: Yup using redis-py. Well ideally I want the tuples to be named after the personsID, so if I have three IDs: 101, 102, and 103, I want the tuple names to be 101_tuple, 102_tuple, and 103_tuple for instance. And have these added to the redis set. This is so I can go back in later and extract these tuples by ID number. 

I'm a bit new to all of this so I don't really understand serialization. Does pickling achieve what I described above?

Comment: I updated the example based on the additional information you provided here. You don't need to use a set or a list in redis, you can just set/get keys. You have to use `pickle` because you need to send redis strings.

Answer (score 0):

If each person have max N attribute, there is language-independent solution based on hash. Here list 3 commands to save/read/delete values for a person.

1. HMSET 'allpersonshash' personID:0  personID:1  ......
2. HMGET 'allpersonshash' personID:0 personID:1 personID:2 ... personID:N
3. HDEL  'allpersonshash' personID:0 personID:1 personID:2 ... personID:N

Answer (score 0):

A fairly general way to do it would be to use sorted sets with json blobs, eg:

```
ZADD userid, '{field1:value1,field2:value2}'
```